# Node Js NPM PDFkit and Voilab pdf table, pdfkit paragraph error afer generate table

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, pdfkit, node-pdfkit

Hi guys thank you for stopping by

i have issues with voilab pdf kit a library for PDFkit which essentially helps for arranging the table for NPM Pdfkit.

after successfully generating table, i tried to add a new paragraph but unfortunately my paragraph format were following row format width and messing up.

let me show you my code to generate table.

```
            doc
                .fontSize(14)
                .font('Times-Bold')
                .text('IKHTISAR POLIS / POLICY SCHEDULE', {
                    align: 'center',
                })
                .text('Asuransi TravelFirst Indonesiana', {
                    align: 'center',
                })
                .font('Times-BoldItalic')
                .text('TravelFirst Indonesiana Insurance', {
                    align: 'center',
                })
                .font('Times-Bold')
                .moveDown(4);

                table
                .addBody([
                    {
                        Item: 'No. Polis / Policy Number',
                        Separator: ':',
                        Description: `${noPolis}`,
                    },
                    {
                        Item: 'Nama / Name',
                        Separator: ':',
                        Description: `${paxes.name}`,

                    },
                    {
                        Item: 'TTL / DOB',
                        Separator: ':',
                        Description: `${DOBpolis}`,
                    },
                    {
                        Item: 'No. Identitas / Identity Number',
                        Separator: ':',
                        Description: `${paxes.id_no}`,
                    },
                    {
                        Item: 'Jenis Perjalanan / Type of Trip',
                        Separator: ':',
                        Description: 'Perjalanan Singkat / Short Trip',
                    },
                    {
                        Item: 'Polis Diterbitkan / Policy Issues',
                        Separator: ':',
                        Description: `${dateNow}`,
                    },
                    {
                        Item: 'Periode Polis / Policy Period',
                        Separator: ':',
                        Description: `${polisStart} - ${polisEnd}`,
                    },
                    {
                        Item: 'Lokasi Asal / Origin Location',
                        Separator: ':',
                        Description: `${element.city_origin}`,
                    },
                    {
                        Item: 'Lokasi Tujuan / Destination Location',
                        Separator: ':',
                        Description: `${element.city_destination}`,
                    },

                    {
                        Item: 'Paket Pilihan / Selected Package',
                        Separator: ':',
                        Description: `${insuranceProduct.name}`,
                    },
                    {
                        Item: 'Jumlah Premi / Total Premi',
                        Separator: ':',
                        Description: `${currencyFormatIDR(insuranceProduct.tarif)}`,
                    },
                    {
                        Item: 'Biaya Polis / Total Premium',
                        Separator: ':',
                        Description: `${currencyFormatIDR(insuranceProduct.tarif)}`,
                    },
                    {
                        Item: 'Jumlah Premi / Total Premi',
                        Separator: ':',
                        Description: `${currencyFormatIDR(insuranceProduct.tarif)}`,
                    },
                ]);
    doc.moveDown(2);
```

and here's my code for add new paragraph after the table

```
        doc
            .fontSize(9)
            .font('Times-Roman')
            .text(tcId, {
                align: 'justify',
                margin: {
                    right: 100,
                },
            });
        doc
            .fontSize(9)
            .font('Times-Italic')
            .text(tcEn, {
                align: 'justify',
                fit: [300, 200],
            });

        doc
            .fontSize(9)
            .font('Times-Roman')
            .text(`${dateNow}`, {
                align: 'right',
                fit: [300, 200],
            });
```

i have tried creating another table and put my paragraph inside like this

```
        table
        .addColumns([
            {
                id: 'text',
                Align: 'justify',
                // width: 500,
            }]);

        table
        .addBody([
            {
                text: `${tcId}`,
            },
            {
                text: `${tcEn}`,
            },
        ]);
```

but the result are the same here's what it looks like after i generate to pdf

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xSdtI.png)

Answer (score 0):

problem solved turns out you need to reset the margin after table.addtable by using doc.x = 0 <<- or any horizontal margin, since voilab-pdf-table works with x, y principals.